# Why does destructor cause segmentation fault?

Tags: destructor

All I do is construct a BNode object. The debugger says that the constructor is causing a segmentation fault. Does anyone know what the problem is here?
All I do is construct a BNode object. The debugger says that the constructor is causing a segmentation fault. Does anyone know what the problem is here?

```
#ifndef BTree_H
#define BTree_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class BNode
{
public:
    BNode();
    BNode(int M);
    ~BNode();
    int keyCount;
    BNode *pointers;
    T *keys;
};

template<typename T>
BNode<T>::BNode()
{

}

template<typename T>
BNode<T>::BNode(int M)
{
    pointers = new BNode<T>[M];
    keys = new T[M - 1];
}

template<typename T>
BNode<T>::~BNode()
{
    delete[] pointers;
    delete[] keys;
}

#endif

int main()
{
    BNode<int> obj(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deleting an *array* of `pointers` and `keys`, whereas you never defined these to be arrays. 
Both of these are ***pointers***.

You need to be freeing memory from the pointers, not arrays.

Try this:-

```
 delete myPointer;
 myPointer = NULL;
```

*NOTE: If you're using C++, read about smart pointers. They'll come in handy!*